# The best / quick way to lean for writing the PHP extension in C

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm leaning to write some minor PHP extension in C for security purpose.

Currently, I can generate the extension use the ext_skel and can separate the source code into multiple files, each file for a class and combine them into the extension.

However currently I stuck on how to use the PHP variable / class / function inside the C code suck as using the GET / POST / SERVER / SESSION, call a php native function likes str_replace or initial a PHP class likes PDO and its methods.

I know that we must to call the C function (from the PHP source) but I don't know to have the best / quick way to find and use them or any documentation to describe using them in the C.

For example, I want to get the $__SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], I must to use the SG(request_info).request_uri from SAPI.h
But I must to google a lot for this one.

Can you instruct me how to find this one with bester way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592037/php-extension-call-existing-php-function

Comment: Thanks @GicuAftene. How about for calling the class from another .so file? For example the PDO class? Should we download the php pdo source and include into the extension?

Comment: Sorry if a respond with only stackoverflow answers; btw here you can find an example of how you could achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998350/php-extension-calling-another-extension-function